# Спасибо за экскурс?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Правильно ли будет сказать: «Спасибо за экскурс»?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Уместность такого высказывания зависит от ситуации. Если вам просто о чём-то рассказали, то вряд ли так можно сказать (не говоря уже о том, что нехорошо было бы и спутать "экскурс" с "экскурсией", большой или маленькой). Другое дело, если у вас была дискуссия на конкретную тему и собеседник, будучи специалистом в области, лишь в отдельном аспекте связанной с этой темой, в своей аргументации подробно осветил для вас частный вопрос и этим помог правильно сориентироваться в том, о чём вы дискутировали. Тогда вы вполне можете его этой фразой поблагодарить, отдавая ему должное как специалисту в своей области: "экскурс" и есть такое сравнительно обширное отступление от основной темы.

Answer (score 2):

ЭКСКУРС, Отступление от главной темы для освещения побочного или дополнительного вопроса. Трактат с историческими экскурсами. Э. в область философии. Краткий э. в современную физику.

Можно сказать: Спасибо за исторический экскурс. (Обычно указывается тематика отступления.)

Answer (score 0):

Сказать-то можно. Вполне нормальная форма благодарности. Но, судя по сомнению, вопрос-то не в форме "спасибо за ...", а о том, когда употребление слова "экскурс" будет правильным, т. е. что именно можно назвать экскурсом.

Если ваше понимание того, что есть экскурс не противоречит словарному, то и говорите на здоровье.

> ЭКСКУРС, -а; м. [лат. excursus] Отступление от главной темы для
>   освещения побочного или дополнительного вопроса. Трактат с
>   историческими экскурсами. Э. в область философии. Краткий э. в
>   современную физику.

Вот за все это можете сказать спасибо. За что-то иное - уже надо другое слово употребить.
К сожалению, "экскурс" сейчас часто понимают неправильно, то ли с дискурсом путая, то ли с лирическим отступлением, то ли вообще с любым более или менее протяженным текстом или речью. Все это, конечно, совершенно неправильно. Ну может,только в ироничном употреблении. когда собеседник беспричинно уходит от темы.